# How do I play many audio files one by one

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I created the 4 UIButtons on the Main StoryBoard.

I would like "Button4" to implement the other buttons function in a row. That means when I press button 4, player 1 should be played first, after that player 2 and after that player 3.

However, when I press "Button4", "Button2" and "Button3" are played at same time.

```
        fileprivate var player1:AVAudioPlayer?
        fileprivate var player2:AVAudioPlayer?
        fileprivate var player3:AVAudioPlayer?

        let url1 = Bundle.main.bundleURL.appendingPathComponent("music1.mp3")
        let url2 = Bundle.main.bundleURL.appendingPathComponent("music2.mp3")
        let url3 = Bundle.main.bundleURL.appendingPathComponent("music3.mp3")

        @IBAction func pushButton1(sender: UIButton) {
            Player(url: url1)
        }

        @IBAction func pushButton2(sender: UIButton) {
            Player1(url: url2)
        }

        @IBAction func pushButton3(_ sender: UIButton) {
            Player2(url: url1, url2: url2, url3: url3)
        }

 //"yourButton2" and "yourButton3" is played at same time in this code at player2

        func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_ player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool) {
            if (player === player1) {
                yourButton.isSelected = false
            } else if (player === player2) {
                yourButton2.isSelected = false
            } else if (player === player3) {
                yourButton.isSelected = false
                player2!.play()
                yourButton2.isSelected = true
                player2!.play()
                yourButton3.isSelected = true
                player1!.play()
            }
        }

        func Player(url: URL) {
            do {
                try player1 = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf:url)
                player1!.play()
                yourButton.isSelected = true
                player1!.delegate = self
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }

        func Player1(url: URL) {
            do {
                try player2 = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf:url)
                player2!.play()
                yourButton2.isSelected = true
                player2!.delegate = self

            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }

        func Player2(url: URL, url2: URL, url3: URL) {
            do {
                try player3 = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf:url)
                try player2 = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url2)
                try player1 = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url3)
                player3!.play()
                yourButton.isSelected = true
                player3!.delegate = self
                player2!.delegate = self
                player1!.delegate = self
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
```

Comment: You chain UIAudio with (UIAudio...). Edit** Rewriting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using an AVAudioPlayer, how about an AVQueuePlayer?

Here's a quick example:

```
var files = ["file1", "file2", "file3"]

var player: AVQueuePlayer = {
    var pathArray = [String]()
    files.forEach { resource in
        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: resource, ofType: "mp3") {
            pathArray.append(path)
        }
    }

    var urlArray = [URL]()
    pathArray.forEach { path in
        urlArray.append(URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
    }

    var playerItems = [AVPlayerItem]()
    urlArray.forEach { url in
        playerItems.append(AVPlayerItem(url: url))
    }

    let player = AVQueuePlayer(items: playerItems)
    player.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEnd.advance

    return player
}()
```

and in your button's action:

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    files = ["file2", "file3", "file1"]
    player.play()
}
```

Admittedly, this is pretty quick and dirty, but something kind of like this because we're passing the files array into the player. It shouldn't be too difficult to find more optimization for this code.

EDIT: realized I wasn't passing in an array of AVPlayerItems, so updated.

Comment: No problem. Let me know if you have other questions.

Answer (score -1):

Edit....

Each of the buttons, 1, 2, 3 etc...will work but "push button 2" is a bit of a mix...

Anyway, reexplain?